# Searching for symbol except within subexpressions with a particular Head

Tags: function-construction, functional-style, code-request, searching

I would like to write a searcher like `FreeQ` that looks for a `Symbol` (or `Head`) in an expression, but confines its search outside of subexpressions that have a particular `Head`.  Because `expr` can get huge, it is especially important to minimize the search time.

For example, I might want to test whether `expr` is free of `Symbol`=`a` outside of `Head`=`func`:

```
expr1 = a * b + c * func[a,x]

expr2 = b^2 + d * func[a,c]
```

Let's call this new searcher `subFreeQ[expr_, symb_, head_]`.  Then I would like:

```
subFreeQ[expr1, a, func]
(*False*)

subFreeQ[expr2, a, func]
(*True*)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just 'hiding' heads:

```
fq[ex_, a_, h_] := FreeQ[ex /. h[x__] :> Unique["x"], a],
```

e.g.

```
fq[b^2 + f[a] + g[a, x] + h[b, x, a], , (f | g | h)]
```

yields `True`